# Retrieving extended properties from contacts using EWS and PowerShell

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

While I'm able to retrieve default contacts properties, i'm looking to retrieve values like Computer Network Name or FTP site.

I understand there some things to add to my code, like every extenededproperties I want to retrieve. I found some sample C# code, but I'm failling so far to write it in PowerShell.

Here's a piece of code where default properties works but not extended ones.

```
$folderid= new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderId([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::Contacts,$MailboxName)   
$Contacts = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder]::Bind($service,$folderid)
$ivItemView =  New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemView(50000)    
$fiItems = $null    

do{    
    $fiItems = $service.FindItems($Contacts.Id,$ivItemView)    
    $psPropset = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.PropertySet([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.BasePropertySet]::FirstClassProperties) 

    $psPropset.Add([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemSchema]::MimeContent)

    #Properties list  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc839633.aspx      
    $ComputerNetworkName = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0x3A49,[Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MapiPropertyType]::String)

    #Add extended properties to properties set
    $psPropset.Add($ComputerNetworkName);
    [Void]$service.LoadPropertiesForItems($fiItems,$psPropset)  

    foreach($Item in $fiItems.Items){

                        $Item.ExtendedProperties | fl *                     
        }

    }    
    $ivItemView.Offset += $fiItems.Items.Count    
}while($fiItems.MoreAvailable -eq $true)
```

If ever some one has a clue...

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding my answer as putting my question here helped me thinking. :)

```
    #Create extended properties
    $ComputerNetworkName = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0x3A49,[Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MapiPropertyType]::String)

    #Add extended properties to properties set
    $psPropset.Add($ComputerNetworkName);
```

Edited my code above to let a working code here for next readers.